# How do wheels reduce the need for energy input for moving items?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Given a large box, it requires a given amount of energy to carry it from location A to location B (either lifting the box, moving, then setting down; or overcoming the floor surface's friction by dragging it...). But if you put the box on a dolley and push, it seems to require much less input of energy to transfer it to the same destination B. Why is less energy required? How do wheels do the 'magic' of reducing the total amount of energy input into the system while still accomplishing the same goal?

Comment: You seem to have come to the answer yourself: wheels are inanimate, with no metabolism, and they roll rather than slide, sharply reducing friction.

Comment: Related: [Mathematically prove that a round wheel roll faster than a square wheel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548519/195139)

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient for rolling friction (without slipping) is very low thereby greatly reducing the effort required for motion compared to sliding and/or lifting.